# trying to rotate a circle continuously in clockwise direction in UWP xaml

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have implemented the structure that is rotating continuously in clockwise direction and now want to implement small circle attached along with it which should also rotate along the same direction in which pointed structure is rotating. Code for that are given below.

## XAML

```xaml
<Grid Name="mainGridView">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Assets/info_bg.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefSubjectHeadingGrid" Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefSubjectListGrid" Height="4.4*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefButtonGrid" Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#339FFE">
            <Image Source="Assets\ic_nytra_logo.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Stretch="Fill" Width="84" Height="72" 
                    Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <Image Source="Assets\ic_setting.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Stretch="Uniform" Width="49" Height="49" 
                    Margin="0,10,15,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Name="Display" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/ic_out_circle.png" Width="230">
                <Image.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection/>
                </Image.Projection>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#339FFE">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

## CS

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private Storyboard rotation = new Storyboard();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.From = 0.0;
        animation.To = 360.0;
        // animation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Display);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.Rotation" + "Z" + ")");
        rotation.Children.Clear();
        rotation.Children.Add(animation);
        rotation.Begin();
    } 
}
```

Image given below

[image: Image of a rotating circle thingy]

Comment: "and now want to implement small circle attached along with it which should also rotate along the same direction" What's stopping you?

Comment: how to implement these all small circle on that pointed structure and it should also rotate in same direction along with pointed structure continuously .this is the problem stopping me.

Comment: If the small and colorful circles are same picture with the 'clockwise direction', when you rotate this picture, all of them will rotate along the same direction, you should not have out of sync issue. If they are not inside one picture, please provide how you layout the 'clockwise' picture and the 12 small circle pictures. Simply to say, does `ic_out_circle.png` contain the small circles?

Comment: All small circle are not the part of single image they are just attached to it at the corner of pointed part of ic_out_circle.png .and they rotate along the same direction as pointed part of ic_out_circle.png in clockwise direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution

```
<Grid x:Name="ImageGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Grid.Projection>            
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,-266,10,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="147,-240,10,0" Fill="#E84C3D" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="245,-134,10,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="285,2,10,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="254,134,10,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="147,240,10,0" Fill="#E84C3D" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,286,10,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-130,252,0,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-239,146,0,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-266,10,10,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-232,-122,10,10" Fill="Orange" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5" />
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-130,-238,10,0" Fill="#E84C3D" Height="47" Width="47" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Image  x:Name="ImageBlock" Source="Assets/ic_out_circle.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Width="230">            
            <Image.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="SpinAnimation">
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0" From="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:5"  Storyboard.TargetName="ImageGrid"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationZ)"/>                 
                            </Storyboard>                                             
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
</Grid>
```